# URLs should ends with the observation id in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

In total I have two files first one is tester and second is the solution for tester file
Here is my Tester File

```
const data = require('./data');
const result0 = data.results[0];
const { getTaxonPhotos } = require('./observations');

const isINaturalistPath = (pathname) =>
  /(square.jpe?g|original.jpe?g|small.jpe?g|medium.jpe?g|large.jpe?g|_s.jpe?g)$/.test(pathname);

const hasIdQueryParam = (search) => /^\?\d+$/.test(search);

const isUrl = (url) => {
  const { pathname, search } = new URL(url);

  if (!isINaturalistPath(pathname)) {
    throw new Error(`URL path doesn't look like an iNaturalist photo: ${pathname}`);
  }

  if (!hasIdQueryParam(search)) {
    throw new Error(`URL origin doesn't have expected id on query string: ${search}`);
  }

  return true;
};

describe('Problem 06 - getTaxonPhotos() function', function () {
  let sample, samples, sampleData;

  beforeEach(() => {
    sample = Object.assign({}, result0);
    samples = [sample];
    sampleData = { results: samples };
  });

  test('should return an Array of Objects with the right URLs', function () {
    let result = getTaxonPhotos(sampleData);
    expect(Array.isArray(result)).toBe(true);
    expect(result.length).toBe(1);

    const photos = result[0];
    expect(isUrl(photos.square)).toBe(true);
    expect(isUrl(photos.original)).toBe(true);
    expect(isUrl(photos.small)).toBe(true);
    expect(isUrl(photos.medium)).toBe(true);
    expect(isUrl(photos.large)).toBe(true);
  });

  test('should return an empty Array if missing taxon', function () {
    delete sample.taxon;

    let result = getTaxonPhotos(sampleData);
    expect(Array.isArray(result)).toBe(true);
    expect(result.length).toBe(0);
  });

  test('real-data should produce the expected result', function () {
    let result = getTaxonPhotos(data);
    expect(Array.isArray(result)).toBe(true);
    expect(result.length).toBe(9);

    result.forEach((photos) => {
      expect(isUrl(photos.square)).toBe(true);
      expect(isUrl(photos.original)).toBe(true);
      expect(isUrl(photos.small)).toBe(true);
      expect(isUrl(photos.medium)).toBe(true);
      expect(isUrl(photos.large)).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  test('URLs should end with the observation ID on the query string', () => {
    let taxonPhotos0 = getTaxonPhotos(data)[0];
    let observationId = result0.id;

    expect(taxonPhotos0.square.endsWith(`?${observationId}`)).toBe(true);
    expect(taxonPhotos0.original.endsWith(`?${observationId}`)).toBe(true);
    expect(taxonPhotos0.small.endsWith(`?${observationId}`)).toBe(true);
    expect(taxonPhotos0.medium.endsWith(`?${observationId}`)).toBe(true);
    expect(taxonPhotos0.large.endsWith(`?${observationId}`)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Here is my solution for the tester file or you can say function to solve the tester code

```
function getTaxonPhotos(data) {
  // TODO
  let patt = /(http(s)?:\/\/)/
  let arr = Array();
  let pho_obj = {
    original: "",
    square: "",
    small: "",
    medium: "",
    large: ""
  };

  data.results.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.hasOwnProperty('taxon') && element.taxon.default_photo) {
      // Separate values and find url and id in them
      let _values = Object.values(element.taxon.default_photo);
      let _url = _values.find(sector => sector.match(patt));
      let _id = _values.find( element => typeof element === 'number').toString();
      let observationId = "1384377507";
      // split the url before file extension
      _url = _url.substring(0, (_url.indexOf(_id) + _id.length + 1));

      // using a for loop with swith to make correct url
      for (let i in pho_obj) {
        switch (`${i}`) {
          case "original":
            pho_obj.original = _url + "original.jpg"+`?${observationId}`;
            break;
          case "square":
            pho_obj.square = _url + "square.jpg"+`?${observationId}`;
            break;
          case "small":
            pho_obj.small = _url + "small.jpg"+`?${observationId}`;
            break;
          case "medium":
            pho_obj.medium = _url + "medium.jpg"+`?${observationId}`;
            break;
          case "large":
            pho_obj.large = _url + "large.jpg"+`?${observationId}`;
            break;
        }
      }
      arr.push(pho_obj);
    }
  });

  return arr;
}
```

I successfully completed 3 conditions but 1 last goes wrong can you help me solve this (I test using jest in javascript)

```
 √ should return an Array of Objects with the right URLs (3 ms)                                                                                        
    √ should return an empty Array if missing taxon                                                                                                       
    √ real-data should produce the expected result (5 ms)                                                                                                 
    × URLs should end with the observation ID on the query string (3 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let taxonPhotos0 = getTaxonPhotos(data)[0];
```

I don't think you have anything define for data

did you try

```
let taxonPhotos0 = getTaxonPhotos(sampleData)[0];
```

Comment: yes but it didn't worked either

Comment: ok... did it give a different error?

Comment: @SahilPatel -- there is a TODO there in your code... looks like it was never finished.  There does not seem to be any code that creates the URLS

Comment: now it's 4 test cases failed